# Cannot get rid of WARNINGS after using DEFINE# and excluding them in PRE-PROCESSOR DEFINITIONS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using VISUAL STUDIO 2017
I keep getting a string of deprecation warnings/errors like

> Error C4996   'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.*

I have started my program by defining:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
```

and have also included these under PROJECT PROPERTIES > C++ > PRE-PROCESSOR

However I still get warnings/errors related to deprecation

If anyone can please help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I fixed some serious formatting issues with your question.  Everything was in bold because you'd peppered your question with `**`'s.

Comment: Works fine for me.  They need to be defined before you include any headers. If you're using a precompiled header they'd need to be at the top of that too.

Comment: Have you looked in to using `sprintf_s`?  Ignoring deprecation warnings is asking for trouble that's known already.

Comment: Thanks.  I have defined everything before any headers.  I still get the warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
**When using with boost**. I placed the #define in:
Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions
(Using a Windows platform with MSVS-2019)